# How to pan in 3DTools:TrackBallDecorator

Tags: object, 3d

I want to pan a 3D object in 3DTools:TrackBallDecorator. It is possible rotating and zooming in 3DTools, but I don't know how to pan. I use VS 2008 C#. My project has XAML codes.

Please, help !...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but here is the answer anyway: Unfortunately, you can't pan in 3DTools. There is an "Enhanced" version which includes panning and it can be found [here.](http://www.kindohm.com/archive/2006/02/01/TrackballsInWPF.html)
Unfortunately, this is outdated as well an you will need to do some work before it compiles, but it might be a starting point.